# Apache Rewrite then Proxy Pass

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy

I have an apache server that works as a reverse proxy in our DMZ. We have an external service that posts back to a particular URL on this server. There is a need now for this service to postback to an entirely new application, but this will most likely change again in the near future as we're in a testing phase right now.

So to resolve this, I'm trying to take the incoming postback request, `/smsPostback.php`, and rewrite it to a new relative URL, `/SMSHandler/Process`. This part is working.

However defined immediately below in the config, I have a ProxyPass directive to proxy all traffic to `/SMSHandler` to an internal server.

These are the new lines from the apache conf file:

```
RewriteRule ^/smsPostback.php$ /SMSHandler/Process 
##Proxy pass smshandler
ProxyPass /SMSHandler http://172.29.61.49:8080/SMSHandler
ProxyPassReverse /SMSHandler http://172.29.61.49:8080/SMSHandler
```

And these are the logs from the rewrite log:

```
172.29.61.49 - - [24/Jan/2012:18:43:36 --0500] [test.hidden.com/sid#5eace0][rid#446b770/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /smsPostback.php
172.29.61.49 - - [24/Jan/2012:18:43:36 --0500] [test.hidden.com/sid#5eace0][rid#446b770/initial] (3) applying pattern '^/smsPostback.php$' to uri '/smsPostback.php'
172.29.61.49 - - [24/Jan/2012:18:43:36 --0500] [test.hidden.com/sid#5eace0][rid#446b770/initial] (2) rewrite '/smsPostback.php' -> '/SMSHandler/Process'
172.29.61.49 - - [24/Jan/2012:18:43:36 --0500] [test.hidden.com/sid#5eace0][rid#446b770/initial] (2) local path result: /SMSHandler/Process
172.29.61.49 - - [24/Jan/2012:18:43:36 --0500] [test.hidden.com/sid#5eace0][rid#446b770/initial] (2) prefixed with document_root to C:/hidden.com/SMSHandler/Process
172.29.61.49 - - [24/Jan/2012:18:43:36 --0500] [test.hidden.com/sid#5eace0][rid#446b770/initial] (1) go-ahead with C:/hidden.com/SMSHandler/Process [OK]
```

And this is the error log entry from apache:

```
[Tue Jan 24 18:43:36 2012] [error] [client 172.29.61.49] File does not exist: C:/fmfacilitymaintenance.com/SMSHandler
```

Any thoughts as to why it never reverse proxies the request, but rather tries (and fails) to serve it locally??  Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to add a `PT` (PassThrough) to your RewriteRule so that apache takes the rewritten URI and passes it back through the URL handling pipeline (so that mod_proxy can handle it). The rule should look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/smsPostback.php$ /SMSHandler/Process [L,PT]
```

Comment: you can drop the `Last`, it's implied with Passthrough http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt

Comment: Is this possible if the rewrite rules are contained in an `.htaccess` file? It seems like my requests are being handled by the proxy first, and then the server that handles the proxied requests doesn't care about the `.htaccess` file. Unfortunately I need to keep the rules contained in that file for biz-rule reasons.

Comment: @AdamTuttle with .htaccess, the matched path is considered relative to the current directory and it doesn't contain the leading "/". Therefore you cannot match on it.