# Apache Rewrite, then Proxy, which order?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, vhosts, mod-proxy

I know it should be pretty easy to use *mod-rewrite* and *mod-proxy* for a Vhost. But I cannot get the right order.

Here is what I want to achieve:

1. Files (JS, CSS, images, fonts, etc.) should be delivered normally
2. XHR requests for certain path (*ibo-php*) should be handled by a proxy, using another Vhost and *http* (not *https*)
3. add a *.php* ending to all these data requests, matching the API path *ibo-php*
4. The Vhost is there for a web-app, which has different app states as path, e.g. */my-app/view/sub-part/1*, so these path parts need to be ignored

The rewrite rules do work for files, but the proxy does not. I am getting a *404* for my calls to the API: **"POST /ec2-app/ibo-php/quarter HTTP/1.1" 404 645 "https://ec2.localhost/ec2-app/"**

(Apache access log, *ec2.localhost* is the name of the Vhost)

I guess that there is something wrong with the order of rules:

```
# for avoiding 403 from https://stackoverflow.com/a/38353249/2092322
<Directory "/home/myname/work/sdp/frontends">
    Require all granted
    RewriteEngine On
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    # background https://stackoverflow.com/a/58307829/2092322
    # now: https://gkedge.gitbooks.io/react-router-in-the-real/content/apache.html
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # the END flag might be a problem, but I currently think that ibo-php is not matched by this rule
    RewriteRule ec2-app/(.*)/(js|style|resources)/(.+)\.(.+)$ ec2-app/$2/$3.$4 [END]

    # "POST /ec2-app/ibo-php/quarter HTTP/1.1" 404 645 "https://ec2.localhost/ec2-app/"
    RewriteRule ec2-app/ibo-php/(.+)$ ec2-app/ibo-php/$1.php [L,PT]

    # anything else to index.html
    RewriteRule ec2-app/(.+) ec2-app/index.html [L]

    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Require all granted
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass ec2-app/ibo-php/ http://ibo-php.localhost:7010/
    ProxyPassReverse ec2-app/ibo-php/ http://ibo-php.localhost:7010/
</Directory>
```

Other sources:
[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003358/apache-rewrite-then-proxy-pass), [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/proxy.html):

> [Here] we proxy the request only if we can't find the resource
> locally. This can be very useful when you're migrating from one server
> to another, and you're not sure if all the content has been migrated
> yet.
>
> ```
> RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}"       !-f
> RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}"       !-d
> RewriteRule "^/(.*)" "http://old.example.com/$1" [P]
> ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://old.example.com/"
> ```
>
> Discussion:
>
> In each case, we add a ProxyPassReverse directive to ensure that any
> redirects issued by the backend are correctly passed on to the client.
>
> Consider using either ProxyPass or ProxyPassMatch whenever possible in
> preference to mod_rewrite.

#### Question

Would all be more easy by using `Alias` or `RewriteBase`?

Comment: You should put your "solution" as an "answer". HOWEVER, the last two `RewriteRule` directives in your `<Directory>` block can't be doing anything - the _pattern_ will never match - since when used in a _directory_ context the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` directive never starts with a slash. (?)

Comment: @MrWhite mh, if this would be the case, the first rule wouldn't do anything, too. Examples for using a slash at the beginning can even be found in the docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html e.g. `RewriteRule "^/images" "-" [F]`

Comment: The "first rule" in your _solution_ is commented out? Yes, most of the doc examples are assuming you are using mod_rewrite in a _server_ (or _virtualhost_) context (which is perhaps a bit confusing). In a _directory_ context (ie. in a `<Directory>` container or `.htaccess`) it behaves differently. As noted in the docs (same page): "In per-directory context (`Directory` and .htaccess), the Pattern is matched against only a partial path, for example a request of "/app1/index.html" may result in comparison against "app1/index.html" or "index.html" depending on where the RewriteRule is defined."

Comment: In the first code block you posted, you omitted the slash prefix (and start-of-string anchor) so these would have potentially matched. (?) Conversely, the `ProxyPass` directive should have a slash prefix on the first argument, but this was omited in your first example, but included in your "solution".

Comment: @MrWhite Alright, thanks. There is a difference. Now I am using the `RewriteRule` according to the docs.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

The right order is

```
<Directory "/home/myname/work/sdp/frontends">
    Require all granted
    RewriteEngine On

    # RewriteRule ec2-app/ibo-php/(.+)$ /ec2-app/ibo-php/$1.php [L,PT]

    # background https://stackoverflow.com/a/58307829/2092322
    # now: https://gkedge.gitbooks.io/react-router-in-the-real/content/apache.html
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ec2-app/(.*)/(js|style|resources)/(.+)\.(.+)$ /ec2-app/$2/$3.$4 [END]

    # anything else to index.html
    RewriteRule ec2-app/(.+) /ec2-app/index.html [L]
</Directory>

LogLevel debug

ProxyPreserveHost On
# "POST /ec2-app/ibo-php/quarter HTTP/1.1" 404 645 "https://ec2.localhost/ec2-app/"
ProxyPassMatch ^/ec2-app/ibo-php/(.+)$ http://ibo-php.localhost:7010/$1.php
ProxyPassReverse ^/ec2-app/ibo-php/ http://ibo-php.localhost:7010/
```

*ProxyPassMatch* is not allowed in `<Directory>`.