# How to make Apache Proxy apply redirects first?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have an Apache configuration where I need to apply both URL redirection and ProxyPass directives. However, I want to ensure that the redirection rules are checked first before proxying the request.

I currently have the following configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    ProxyPreserveHost off
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLProxyVerify off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

    ProxyPass /shop https://example.com/shop
    ProxyPassReverse /shop https://example.com/shop

</IfModule>
```

My redirects are still in a `.htaccess` file, but I guess if needed I can move them to the same configuration file where the proxy rules are.

`Redirect 301 "/shop/xxxx/xxxx/xxx/xxxx" "/shop/xxxx/xxxx"`

the ProxyPass directives are being processed before the redirection rules. As a result, the requests matching the redirection pattern are not being redirected and are instead proxied.

I would like to ensure that the redirection rules are checked first, and if a match is found, a redirection should be performed. Only if there is no matching redirection, the request should be proxied using the ProxyPass directives.

Is there a way to achieve this combination of redirection and ProxyPass directives in the desired order? Any guidance or alternative solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003358/apache-rewrite-then-proxy-pass